# Site to get feedback

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have Class for a Template Engine that I wrote, and it is in it's alpha stages, is there a StackExchange site I can go to, to get feedback on this class (Functionality, and not the code it's self)?

I would like a site to get feedback about what features I could add/remove/change.

Comment: perhaps codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is still in beta, but should be the place to go.

From their [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Code Review - Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review.

You should probably say what kind of feedback you are looking for in your question though. Read the FAQ to see what is acceptable.

Comment: At that site, can I also ask for what features could I add to the Engine? Or is that off topic? I don't really want "code review" but for people to test the class is what I want reviewed.

Comment: @RyanNaddy - Not sure. Ask that on their [Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. I'd guess that it isn't on-topic, but it might be.

Comment: @RyanNaddy Speaking as a relatively high rep Code Review user, asking for what features you could add would be off topic, the site is concentrated on code reviews. That said if you follow the site's FAQ and post your code for review (regardless of if that's what you're truly interested in or not), I'm guessing that people wouldn't really mind if you also asked for a functionality review as well. Just make sure to not make it your primary question and be prepared that answerers might just ignore your secondary question.